# TMG setup exit with installation failed error when adding network adapter

Tags: microsoft-ftmg

I have setup a server for TMG installation. When I run setup it works fine until it gives me option to setect network. When I click on add option to select internal network, setup exit and gives an error of installation failed. Event log shows following message:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While troubleshooting further, it was noticed that the ISO file was mounted using UltraISO. The ISO extractor tool stripped the file properties that had the digital signature and version info. After extracting setup files from ISO using WinRAR, installation successfully completed.

[This](http://blogs.technet.com/b/isablog/archive/2010/07/13/another-tmg-2010-installation-failure-with-error-0x80070643.aspx) is link to source that helped in identifying logs and resolving problem.